# Как реализовать интерактивную карту

Tags: javascript, css, svg, raphael

[image: Карта]

Как реализовать данную карту, при наведении менять цвет страны а при нажатии ставить метку и естественно отдавать какой-то параметр на бекэнд, мои предположения это svg карта плюс js, но опять опыта реализации нет?
Подскажите как реализовать или же если я правильно думаю то ткните на хорошую статью.
Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Зачем предполагать, когда можно посмотреть с помощью чего это сделано в Firebug/WebInspector?

Comment: В смысле? Это же скрин макета)

Comment: Примеры карт с использованием d3.js:
https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/17/d3-js-mouse-events-and-transitions-tutorial/
http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать с помощью Google Maps.

Вам нужно будет найти координаты полигонов в raw формате (если Вы желаете использовать kml формат, помните, что он умеет обрабатывать только click событие).

Далее нужно создать полигоны, как, можно найти в поиске: Google Maps Polygon Example

Объект Polygon умеет обрабатывать нужные Вам события (click, mouseover, ...), нужно только назначить Ваш обработчик, документацию можно найти в поиске: Google Maps Polygon Options

Оформление можно сделать с помощью Google Maps Wizard

P.S. Для вставки ссылок не хватает рейтинга

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать замечательную JS библиотеку для карт – LeafletJS. Вот и урок по созданию карты как вы хотите – называется [Interactive Choropleth Map](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html)

Answer (score 1):

Эта задача полностью решается через [API Яндекс.Карт](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/?from=SO). По пунктам:

1. Добавить страны мира на карту и раскрасить их можно через модуль [Регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/?from=SO). [Пример в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions?from=SO) и [пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4enqtcL5/1/), где сделана карта мира без подложки.

   ```
   ymaps.regions.load('001', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 1
   }).then(function (result) {
    var regions = result.geoObjects; 
    map.geoObjects.add(regions);
   }, function () {
    alert('No response');
   });
   ```
2. Обрабатывать клики по полигонам стран можно через систему событий, пример есть [в этой статье документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/?from=SO#each).
3. По клику также можно ставить метку в точку клика, вот так:

   ```
   myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var coords = e.get('coords');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(coords))
   });
   ```

Подробно решение с помощью API Яндекс.Карт рассмотрено в этом вопросе: [Как сделать интерактивную карту мира без подписей / контурную карту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768744/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83/)