# Как сделать интерактивную карту мира без подписей / контурную карту

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Нужно сделать карту стран мира без лишней детализации - отключить фон карты, подписи населенных пунктов, географические объекты и показать только границы стран нужного цвета.

На карте нужно обрабатывать клики по странам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать такую карту можно с помощью модуля [Регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/?from=SO) API Яндекс.Карт. Он позволяет добавить на карту полигоны стран или регионов страны и работать с ними как с [геообъектами](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/GeoObject-docpage/?from=SO).

Ниже показан пример создания карты мира без подложки, по клику на страну открывается балун с её названием.

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

  //Создаем карту
  map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [50, 30],
    zoom: 2,
    controls: [],
    type: null //отключает стандартную подложку карты
  }, {
    minZoom: 1, //ограничиваем зум карты
    maxZoom: 5,
    restrictMapArea: [
      [85, -169],
      [-70, 190]
    ] //ограничиваем область видимости карты
  });

  //Добавляем белый фон карты
  map.layers.add(new ymaps.Layer('https://sandbox.api.maps.yandex.net/examples/ru/2.1/azimuthal_map/images/tiles_arctic/3/tile-0-0.jpg'));


  //загружаем страны мира (код '001') на русском языке в стандартном качестве
  ymaps.regions.load('001', {
    lang: 'ru',
    quality: 1
  }).then(function(result) {
    var regions = result.geoObjects; // ссылка на коллекцию GeoObjectCollection

    //настраиваем дефолтный внешний вид полигонов
    regions.options.set({
      fillColor: '#8ca9cf99',
      strokeColor: '#FFF',
      pixelRendering: 'static',
      hasHint: false
    });

    //перекрашиваем нужные регионы
    regions.each(function(reg) {
      if (reg.properties.get('name') == "Россия" || reg.properties.get('name') == "Беларусь" || reg.properties.get('name') == "Украина") {
        //Меняем цвет 
        reg.options.set('fillColor', '#89e8e099')
      }
    });

    //обрабатываем клики по странам
    result.geoObjects.events.add('click', function(e) {
      //определяем полигон, в который кликнули, и координаты клика
      var regClicked = e.get('target'),
        coords = e.get('coords');
      //открываем балун с названием страны в точке клика
      regClicked.properties.set('balloonContent', regClicked.properties.get('name'));
      regClicked.balloon.open(coords);
    });
    //добавляем регионы на карту 
    map.geoObjects.add(regions);
  }, function() {
    //фоллбек на случай незагрузки регионов
    alert('No response');
  });


}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
```

[Пример работы модуля Регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/regions?from=SO) в песочнице Яндекса.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут есть прекрсное видео для построения таких карт https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkyJvFA_2dQ